# Prove ratio of curvature and torsion = -sin d/ sinφ dφ where  and φ are angles between a fixed vector and the tangent and binormal respectively

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I'm trying to prove the following:

> If the tangent and binormal at a point of a curve make angles  and φ respectively with a fixed direction, then prove that $\frac{\sin{\theta} \ d\theta}{\sin{\phi} \ d\phi} = -\frac{\kappa}{\tau}$ where $\kappa$ is the curvature, and $\tau$ is the torsion of the curve.

So far, I've tried simplifying it from both the RHS and the LHS.

First I drew [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baXzX.png):

To help you visualize, it's a downward opening parabola-like curve. It lies flat on the xy plane.

$\vec{X}$ is a unit vector pointing in the fixed direction.

**My approach from the LHS was as follows:**

- Draw [a diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg07m.png) with $\vec{T}$, $\vec{T} + \vec{dT}$, $\vec{X}$, and $\theta$. The angle between $\vec{T} + \vec{dT}$ and $\vec{X}$ is $\theta + d\theta$.
- $d\theta = (\theta + d\theta) - \theta$, so I find the angle between $\vec{T} + \vec{dT}$ and $\vec{X}$ using projections, hoping to end up with some kind of trigonometric function and then I can go from there to the RHS.
- Repeat same for $\phi$.
- Simplify fraction to RHS.

However, this didn't work out since I ended up with a huge $arccos$ subtraction, and I stopped there since I was clearly doing something wrong.

**My approach from the RHS:**

- Use relations between $\kappa$, $\tau$, $\vec{T}$, $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{N}$ to arrive at a simpler expression in terms of vectors.
- Somehow introduce $\theta$ and $\phi$ into the expression and take it from there to the LHS.

I simplified it to
$$\frac{\left|\frac{d\vec{T}}{dt}\right|^2}{\frac{d\vec{B}}{dt} \cdot \frac{d\vec{T}}{dt}}$$

But that was about it. I'm not sure how I can introduce $\theta$ or $\phi$ into this.

How do I proceed?

**Edit**:

A friend suggested a much simpler idea: implicit differentiation.

We know,

$$\vec{T} \cdot \vec{X} = \cos \theta$$
$$\vec{B} \cdot \vec{X} = \cos \phi$$

Differentiating the two implicitly,

$$d\vec{T} \cdot \vec{X} = - \sin \theta d\theta$$
$$d\vec{B} \cdot \vec{X} = - \sin \phi d\phi$$

Simplifying LHS a little,

$$dT \cdot X \cdot \cos(d\vec{T}, \vec{X}) = - \sin \theta d\theta$$
$$dB \cdot X \cdot \cos(d\vec{B}, \vec{X}) = - \sin \phi d\phi$$

Now I want to divide these, but I don't know the angle $(d\vec{T}, \vec{X})$ and $(d\vec{B}, \vec{X})$. Did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use descriptive titles. "How do I proceed with proving this?" says nothing about the subject of the question. It's a useless title. Here's [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: This is the first time in my life I encounter the symbol $\varnothing$ as a variable! You may have to change the title of your question so that it appears informative. I dont know, maybe *Deriving the ratio between curvature and torsion* or something?

Comment: @Didier Oops, my bad. I accidentally copied the wrong character and I kept copy pasting the same one.

Comment: In case the curves lies in a plane the torsion vanishes.

Comment: You are forgetting to use the Frenet equations, i.e., the definitions of $\kappa$ and $\tau$. I think the problem needs an additional hypothesis: You need to know the fixed vector is not in the plane spanned by $T$ and $N$ (and hopefully there’s no dividing by $0$ in the given equation).

Comment: P.S. No implicit differentiation is required. Write everything as functions of the arclength parameter of the curve. Then differentials disappear and you have, e.g., $(\sin\theta(s))\theta'(s)$, etc. Arclength parametrization is what you want to invoke definitions of curvature and torsion, anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. To be clear, I divided the dot product of the vectors, not the vector X.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gRo9.jpg

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.